# Align button regardless length of paragraph

Tags: html, css

I have a page with this structure. I want the titles to align and the paragraphs to start on the same line and the buttons to all be aligned regardless how long the paragraph is. How do I achieve this? Preferbly without using Grid

```css
.wrapper{display:flex}
.inside{
width:100px;

}
p{word-wrap: break-word;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inside">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>adsdadsa</p>
  <button>Click</button>
  </div>
    <div class="inside">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>afasfasfasfasfasfsafasfsafsafasfsafsfasfsa</p>
  <button>Click</button>
  </div>
    <div class="inside">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>adsdadsa</p>
  <button>Click</button>
  </div>
    <div class="inside">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>adsdadsa</p>
  <button>Click</button>
  </div>
    <div class="inside">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>adsdadsa</p>
  <button>Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if all the titles are the same add `display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;` to `.inside` and `margin-top:auto` to button. If all the titles aren't the same see the first duplicate

Comment: but then the paragraph doesnt start in the same place?

Comment: I hope this helps you - https://ibb.co/DR0LVSy